# C++ неправильно работает оператор пересечения мультимножеств

Tags: c++, множества

У меня есть реализация мультимножества слов, и операция пересечения двух мультимножеств, `*` , выдает неправильный результат. Помогите понять, почему?
Вот реализация самой операции:

```cpp
WSet& WSet::operator *=(const WSet& r)
{
    WSet res;
    for(auto it1 = begin(); it1 != end(); it1++)
        for(auto it2 = r.begin(); it2 != r.end(); it2++)
            if (*it1 == *it2){
                int cnt = min(it1.count(), it2.count());
                res.add(*it1, cnt);
                break;
            }
    *this = res;
    return *this;
}
```

Вот остальной код:

```cpp
WSet::WSet() {}

WSet::WSet(const WSet& other) {
    WordLN* it = other.head;
    while(it != nullptr)
    {
        this->add(it->data, it->cnt);
        it = it->next;
    }
};

WSet::WSet(WSet&& other) : head(other.head)
{
    other.head = nullptr;
}

WSet::~WSet()
{
    WordLN* it = head, *temp;
    while(it != nullptr)
    {
        temp = it->next;
        delete it;
        it = temp;
    }
}

WSet& WSet::operator =(const WSet& r)
{
    if (&r != this)
    {
        WordLN* it = r.head;
        while(it != nullptr)
        {
            this->add(it->data, it->cnt);
            it = it->next;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

WSet& WSet::operator =(WSet&& r)
{
    if (&r != this)
    {
        head = r.head;
        r.head = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

void WSet::add(T data, int cnt)
{
    if (cnt <= 0)
        return;
    if (head == nullptr || data < head->data)
    {
        WordLN* elem = new WordLN{data, head, cnt};
        head = elem;
        return;
    }
    WordLN* p = head;
    while(p->next != nullptr && data >= p->next->data)
        p = p->next;
    if (data == p->data)
    {
        p->cnt += cnt;
    }
    else if (data > p->data)
    {
        WordLN* elem = new WordLN{data, p->next, cnt};
        p->next = elem;
    }
}

void WSet::del(T data)
{
    WordLN* p = head;
    if (head == nullptr || data < p->data)
        return;
    else if (data == p->data)
    {
        p->cnt--;
        if (p->cnt == 0)
        {
            head = p->next;
            delete p;
            return;
        }
    }
    WordLN* p1;
    while(p->next != nullptr && data > p->data)
    {
        p1=p;
        p=p->next;
    }
    if (data == p->data)
    {
        p->cnt--;
        if (p->cnt == 0)
        {
            p1->next=p->next;
            delete p;
        }
    }
}

void WSet::set0()
{
    WordLN* p = head, *temp;
    while(p != nullptr)
    {
        temp = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = temp;
    }
    head = nullptr;
}

WSet WSet::operator +(const WSet& r) const
{
    WSet res;
    for(auto it = begin(); it != end(); it++)
        res.add(*it, it.count());
    int cnt;
    for(auto it1 = r.begin(); it1 != r.end(); it1++)
    {
        cnt = it1.count();
        for(auto it2 = res.begin(); it2 != res.end(); it2++)
            if (*it1 == *it2)
            {
                cnt = max(0, cnt - it2.count());
                break;
            }
        res.add(*it1, cnt);
    }
    return res;
}

WSet::WIter::WIter() {}

WSet::WIter::WIter(WordLN* init) : cur(init) {}

T WSet::WIter::operator *()
{
    return cur->data;
}

WSet::WIter WSet::WIter::operator ++()
{
    cur = cur->next;
    return *this;
}

WSet::WIter WSet::WIter::operator ++(int)
{
    WIter temp(cur);
    cur = cur->next;
    return temp;
}

bool WSet::WIter::operator ==(const WIter& r)
{
    return cur == r.cur;
}

bool WSet::WIter::operator !=(const WIter& r)
{
    return cur != r.cur;
}

int WSet::WIter::count()
{
    return cur->cnt;
}

WSet::WIter WSet::begin() const
{
    return WIter(head);
}

WSet::WIter WSet::end() const
{
    return WIter();
}
```

UPD: Проблема решена, она заключалась в неправильном операторе присвоения, правильно вот так:

```cpp
WSet& WSet::operator =(const WSet& r)
{
    if (&r == this)
        return *this;
    set0();
    for(auto it = r.begin(); it != r.end(); it++)
        add(*it, it.count());
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Квадратичный алгоритм для пересечения сетов - брррррр...

Comment: Где [mcve] чтобы это можно было скомпилировать?

Comment: Ты бы header сюда выложил. А то странно выходит.

Comment: @Qwertiy писал бы для себя  - написал бы за линию, но боюсь, что те, для кого я пишу, не поймут

Comment: @Qwertiy а насчёт статьи - спасибо, был неправ, учту на будущее

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (*it1 == *it2){
> ```
>
> ```
> bool WSet::WIter::operator !=(const WIter& r)
> {
>     return cur != r.cur;
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> WSet::WIter::WIter(WordLN* init) : cur(init) {}
> ```

Судя по всему, вместо ключей сетов ты сравниваешь указатели на узлы, в которых хранятся и ключи, и количества.

Возможно, должно быть что-то такое:

```
bool WSet::WIter::operator !=(const WIter& r)
{
    return cur->data != r.cur->data;
}
```

А вообще, для таких вещей есть отладчик.

Comment: *it возвращает значение в узле, так что я сравниваю именно значения в том куске кода

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы обьявляете   `WSet res;` то в этом обьекте ничего нет, поэтому после  `res.add(*it1, cnt);` (хотя не понятно, для чего числа добавлять в мультимножества слов. Логичнее добавлять слово) в этом временном обьекте не будут находится все нужные данные, и после присваивания  `*this = res;` в обьекте будет находится только одно число(по видимому). Не внимательно прочитал весь остальной код, но кажется ваш класс выполняет операции непонятные логике. вдобавок, результату вы пытаетесь добиваться сложным путем. И, так как, не понятно что вы пытаетесь делать в данной и в других операциях, то можно только догадыватся как будет правильно написать оператор. Точный ответ можно будет формулировать только после хорошей формулировки вопроса(вместе с описанием того, что пытаетесь получать... В дополнении: раз уж определили итераторный класс, используйте стандартные алгоритмы и получите быстрый и правильный результат.